# Add level column to a dataframe with factor column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following toy example of my df:

```
    structure(list(a = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = "factor"), b = c("ku", "pu", "dd", "ka", "la", 
"gu", "kuku", "pupu", "d", "a", "su", "mo", "kui", "pue", "vwe", 
"rr", "wq", "q", "ppr", "tr", "qs", "cf")), .Names = c("a", "b"
), row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I want to transform `a` to be factor object and to populate it's levels to an additional column (with level 1 corresponding to 1's, 2 to 2's etc.)

Please advise how can I add this additional factor level column?

The desired output should be:

```
a   b     a_lev
1   k      1
1   v      1
1   fs     1 
1   fdf    1
2   fe     2
3   ee     3
2   ere    2 
1   rre    1 
2   rerere 2 
3   rer    3
2   ere    2
1   fd     1
1   fd     1
```

Comment: Just do `df$new <- factor(df$a)`  Or using `dplyr` `df %>% mutate(new = factor(a))`

Comment: I need the levels column, I know I need to add factor(df$a)

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear.  Is `a` a `factor` already?  Based on your expected output, there is not any difference between 'a' and 'a_lev'

Comment: a is factor, sorry for not mentioning it @akrun

Comment: @akrun done plz have a look

Comment: @akrun b column is just toy, you can put anything there, you can even eliminate it, the main question is to take 1 factor column and add a column of it's levels.

Comment: Do you need `levels(df$a)[df$a]`

Comment: Yes exactly, please explain what is done here, is it get a level for each row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We extract the `levels` of the column and then expand it by matching with the element

```
df$a_lev <- levels(df$a)[df$a]
```

The `class` will be `character`,  So, it is easier to use `as.character`

```
df$a_lev <- as.character(df$a)
```

Comment: And in general if I want my levels to be numeric?

Comment: @steves  Then just coerce to numeric `as.integer(df$a_lev)`  For example `set.seed(24); v1 <- factor(sample(LETTERS[1:5], 20, replace = TRUE)); as.integer(v1)`